# Passing parameters in Laravel 5.2 Registration Form Update-proof

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am using the standard Laravel 5.2 authentication.

But i want to have certain variables available in my Registration view

The route that i'm interested in is this one:

```
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
```

The method showRegistrationForm is created in a `trait called RegistersUsers` , This trait is located in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` .

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'registerView')) {
            return view($this->registerView);
        }

        return view('auth.register');
    }
```

I can just simply pass trough my parameters here, but the problem is that this file is located in the vendor directory , so when i run Composer Update my changes will be overwritten & my website would break. Is there a update-proof way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite the method in your AuthController:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    ....

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {

        $data = ['foo', 'bar'];

        if (property_exists($this, 'registerView')) {
            return view($this->registerView, compact('data'));
        }

        return view('auth.register', compact('data'));
    }


}
```

Comment: i did not know that! Thank you